# Problem with version of Bootstrap, migration from bootstrap3 to boostrap4

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I first installed the bootstrap version     `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",`, everything was working good. but I could not use a card.

Example:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to switch on the Bootstrap 4 version `"bootstrap": "4.1.1",` and nothing has changed. This is the style in my `angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "styles.css"
        ],
```

I want to mention I use the `ngx-bootstrap` for my popup, and it works good. 
My `package.json` :

```
{
    "name": "ui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
        "protractor-jasmine2-reporter": "^1.1.0",
        "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.6",
        "zone.js": "0.8.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "2.0.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "protractor": "5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "4.1.0",
        "tslint": "5.9.1",
        "typescript": "2.5.3"
    }
}
```

I tried to add `bootstrap` link  in my `index.html`, after that the card worked, but my popup was not working.

Bootstrap link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Does anyone know where I made mistake?

Comment: did you try bootstrap 4.0.0 just as: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap.md

Comment: This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap popups, modals, carousels, etc you need to link bootstrap js scripts